# How to see our rank in tags?

Tags: support

How we can see our rank in specified tag. For example, if someone active in `Symfony2` tag :

1. How we can see his current rank in `Symfony2` tag from all the time?
2. How to see my own rank in `Symfony2` tag from all the time?

**--EDIT--**

I saw somewhere in comments but I can not find where, they are talking about #1 rank in one tag, how they know it?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Click on the tag, follow the "top users" link.

Comment: @Mat : thank you, so we just can saw top users not for our current rank if you are not in top?

Comment: There is no ranking over time, only the current ranking is available for the top 20 names (with your own always added on if you are not in the top 20).

Comment: See [this comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296212/is-there-a-way-to-see-your-tag-percentile-rank#comment203383_296212)

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112288/how-do-i-find-my-rank-for-a-specific-tag