# Is there a way to see your tag percentile rank?

Tags: discussion

In StackOverflow Careers, you can see your highly ranked tags in the top 10th, 20th, and 30th percentile. Example:

[image: tag percentiles]

Is there a query that you can run to to find out your own percentile in any tag? I am curious because I would like to know what my percentile rank in the javascript tag is, since I am not at the 30th percentile yet.

Comment: Use [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/70971/what-percentile-am-i-in-for-a-given-tag).