# How is the tag percentile displayed on my CV computed?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

I noticed on my CV that I am in the top 30% for the Javascript tag. I got curious about what exactly I am in the top 30% of, and a quick search on Meta led me to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296212/is-there-a-way-to-see-your-tag-percentile-rank) and [this data query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/70971/what-percentile-am-i-in-for-a-given-tag).

But according to this query, I am in the top 12% for Javascript, and according to the question linked above the thresholds are at 10, 20 and 30 so I should see top 20% on my CV.
What's more, I realised I am also in the top 16% for Python and top 17% for Java, but these tags don't appear on my CV.

Why is that? How is the CV percentile computed exactly (if it's not a secret)?

Comment: *if it's not a secret* ... It is a Secret™ ofc

Comment: I can't close as duplicate, but the answer is here, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121074/top-x-in-tag-rules-for-the-tag-to-be-taken-into-account.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Juice, but from what I understand it does not answer the question. What I understood is that the tag appears if I am in the top 30% or less all-time answerers for that tag. According to the data query, I am in the top **20%** for Javascript, Java and Python (is the query wrong?). The tag also needs to be answered by at least 500 people on careers. I'd be very surprised if Python and Java do not qualify...

Comment: (I don't want to look like I pretend to be a guru in any of these languages, I just would like to understand this ranking)